# gThumb won't open from its own .desktop file nor from thunar, xdg-open is ok

Tags: desktop, thunar, xdg-open

gThumb doesn't start when launched from Thunar (right click, open with, gThumb).
I also can't run it with `dex /user/local/share/application/org.gnome.gThumb.desktop`.
In both cases nothing happens, no errors.

It works with:

- Starting gThumb from the `gthumb` command line
- Launching gThumb with `xdg-open myfile.jpg' is fine. (and mime is associated with the gThumb desktop file. see below)
- Starting gThumb from my launcher (fuzzel)

```
xdg-mime query default image/jpeg
org.gnome.gThumb.desktop
```

At this point, I don't know what's happening. It does not seem to affect other applications.

Any idea ?

OS: Arch up-to-date - DE: sway (wayland)

EDIT: just saw that all process (from all my tries) are still running. Maybe wayland related ?